# How do I change the number identification format (to associate with a contact's number)?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts

I have a Sony/Ericsson Xperia Arc phone with Android 2.3 In my country, I can receive calls with the following number patterns (it's the formatting used by my operator):

```
12345678
0aa12345678
0bbaa12345678
```

However, my system won't identify the second and third options as being a number from the same contact. That's the behavior that I want: if some contact's number is 12345678, the phone software should always match with the contact if the 8 number from right to left match.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

The 'aa' and 'bbaa' fields are just numbers. An example of a number could be:

01122223333

**aa** is a kind of region code and **bb** is the operator's code.In this case, if I have 22223333 in my contacts, it won't match. If I have 0441122223333 in my contacts, it won't work either. But it should (and I think that some cheap cell phones sold by operators have this behavior in my country).

Comment: Just for curiosity: Which operator in what country do you talk about?

Comment: TIM operator in Brazil.

Comment: Do the numbers that you receive calls from that look like the second and third examples above actually include letters or are you using `bbaa` as an representation/variable?

Comment: Just edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Give a try to `Rocket Dial` free or pro available in Play store. In the setting you will find to change the no. format according to your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the format +bbaa12345678 in your contacts (so you replace the 0 by a + sign).

Comment: It works for receiving calls, but then I cannot use this number to make calls. My operator gives me an "invalid number" error.

Comment: Maybe try `+55bbaa12345678`?

Comment: Doesn't work either. :(