# The Way Numbers Are Displayed/Broken Up

Tags: contacts, localization

I live in Jordan and just got a Galaxy SIII. I have a problem with the way numbers are being displayed on the dialer and when you actually press the green button to place a call.

Basically, the phone breaks up the number, including the prefix, by inserting spaces. For example, let’s say my number is `0787777707` (078 being the prefix of the phone operator). The phone displays it as `07 87 77 77 07`. How can I fix it so it displays it as one series, `0787777707`? My  iPhone has a simiar issue, but that could be addressd once you change the regional format. I can’t find that on the Galaxy though.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11022/is-it-somehow-possible-to-change-manually-the-format-of-a-telephone-number

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22033/how-do-i-change-the-number-identification-format-to-associate-with-a-contacts

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/is-it-somehow-possible-to-change-the-format-of-a-telephone-number-being-displaye

Comment: None of these solutions solved the problem :(

Comment: What language do you have set?

Comment: English UK... I tried English Singapore as well. Nothing changed.